# Multiple fill styles in 3D Gnuplot graphs using splot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using Gnuplot 5.0.0 to plot multiple intersecting surfaces, which I have set to be transparent. However, I am also mapping some points to these surfaces to indicate how the surfaces are explored during the course of a calculation. The trouble is that the points are not easily visible as they have also been made transparent by the line

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.60 border
```

which makes everything in the plot transparent to the same extent. Using a Gnuplot tutorial on transparency (http://www.gnuplotting.org/filledcurves-with-different-transparency/), I tried the following to set the surface transparency independent of that of the points:

```
splot 'surffile' with pm3d palette fs transparent solid 0.60
```

But using this method, I get the error "unexpected or unrecognized token", so it seems to me that the the fs method of setting transparency is incompatible with `splot`.

Is there a way that I can make my surfaces transparent, whilst leaving the points on the surface opaque?

**Edit: MCVE**

```
set palette rgb 21,22,23
set pm3d depthorder border linetype -1 linewidth 0.5
splot 'dplgwp01' u 2:3:5 w points,\
      'dplgwp01' u 2:3:4 w points,\
      'pesd1' with pm3d palette fs transparent solid 0.60,\
      'pesd2' u 1:2:3 with pm3d palette fs transparent solid 0.60
```

dplgwp01 contains data points that I want to remain opaque, whilst pesd1 and pesd2 are surfaces that I want to be transparent.

Comment: You could get much more help if you could provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the advice - updated.

Comment: I have a partial solution using multiplot and unset style after plotting the transparent surfaces; however, this is only suited to plotting for animations or static images, not a fully rotatable plot.

Comment: but reversing the order of the plot is not enough? i.e. plotting the `pesd` before the  `dplgwp` ?

Comment: `splot pesd` before `splot dplgwp` results in only the points being displayed after rotation? And vice versa leaves just the surfaces. From what I understand of `multiplot`, it's not possible to use this to solve my problem.